# Focus Button in a ListView when key is pressed

Tags: c#, wpf, controls, key-bindings

I'm displaying buttons in a `ListView` (instead of text). I do that, because I have to load products from a db and have the same amount of buttons on my GUI.
The whole GUI needs to be fully controlable via keyboard, so I added `KeyBindings` to those buttons. The problem is that those buttons need to be focused twice. First the item is focused, second the button is focused and my `KeyBinding` works.
This has to be done much easier for the user and I don't know how to implement a method which focuses the button, because those buttons don't have names (dynamic content).

Here's my XAML:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Produkte}" Grid.Row="0">
            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <UniformGrid IsItemsHost="True" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <UniformGrid>
                        <Button Template="{DynamicResource ButtonBaseControlTemplate1}" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle1}" Command="{Binding DataContext.BestellenCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}">
                            <Button.Background>
                                <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding PictureUrl}" />
                            </Button.Background>
                            <DockPanel>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Bezeichnung}" FontSize="30"  DockPanel.Dock="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0, 25, 0, 0"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Preis}" FontSize="15" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Shortcut}" FontSize="15" HorizontalAlignment="Right" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="5"/>
                            </DockPanel>
                            <Button.InputBindings>
                                <KeyBinding Key="{Binding Shortcut}" Command="{Binding DataContext.BestellenCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
                            </Button.InputBindings>
                        </Button>
                    </UniformGrid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

I hope you have experience in dynamic controls with KeyBindings.
Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Stefan

Comment: Does setting Focusable to false for ListBoxItem in ItemContainerStyle help?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't. I've talked to my C# teacher and he said the easiest way is to break with MVVM and add a method in the code behind.